# Backbone.Model.destroy not triggering success function on success

Tags: backbone.js

So, within one of my views, I've got this function:

```
delete_model: function() {
    var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this element?");
    if (answer) {
        this.model.destroy({
            success: function() {
                console.log("delete was a success");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

When I ping that, the Ajax call goes out, the backend properly deletes the model and returns a 200 header with "OK" as the body...but the success event never fires.  Am I missing something? What should I have the backend serve to fire that event?

Comment: Maybe, just maybe response body should be empty. Just return 200 response code. That is how I do it. I believe that if you return anything but JSON you have got a backbone error. And just a good habit is to handle errors.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I just had the same problem. The solution that worked for me was to make sure I return a json model from the server that corresponds to the deleted one.

**edit:** returning an empty json response will suffice.

Did not work:

```
delete(model) {
    // deleted model from db
    return "Model was deleted";
}
```

This did work:

```
delete(model) {
    // deleted model from db
    return model;
}
```

or:

```
delete(id) {
  // deleted model from db with this id
  return new Model {id: id};
```

}

Comment: I think returning any JSON would do. Returning anything but JSON would be an error.

Comment: @IvanIvanić that is not the case.  As Zek's answer points out, `render json: 'success'` still fails, as I've confirmed as well.  The minimal working response I've found (for Rails) was `render json: {}` (response in success callback is {}) or `render json: ''` (response in success callback is null)

Comment: Validating that sending back empty JSON - {} does trigger a success.

Comment: Perfect. Should be the accepted answer (perhaps with a note to what @RyanOgle says).

Comment: It also works for me. In express (node.js) I had to replace response.send(200); with response.send({});

Comment: Worked for me but I wonder if this is correct behavior on the part of backbone? a 200 should suffice. I'm considering opening an issue on this

Comment: @manuelhe this is true a 200 should be enough, I don't know why it does this.

Comment: @IvanIvanić thanks for your comment, returning a json now works :P

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem using Backbone 1.5.3 with Rails. I tried rudena's solution, and it works!

Here's what my controller's delete function looked like initially:

```
def destroy
  @cell = current_user.cells.find(params[:id])
  @cell.destroy

  render :json => "success"
end
```

And here's what worked:

```
def destroy
  @cell = current_user.cells.find(params[:id])
  @cell.destroy

  render :json => @cell
end
```

Comment: This answer is specific to Rails, but +1.

Answer (score 2):

That looks good to me, exactly what I have everywhere (except I have `function(model)` but that shouldn't matter at all) I do know that older versions of backbone didn't use the `destroy(options)` but instead had `destroy(success, failure)`.  Can you make sure you have the latest version.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but the version I was using definitely had the single `options` argument -- and with the newer version, I'm still getting the weird behavior. I still haven't sussed this out, and am just doing something of a hail mary where I send the DELETE and assume success (...yeah, not good -- the project is still very much in the alpha stage). Will post back when I get to the bottom of it.

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem come up with my UI as well. Upon `DELETE`, the API came back with an empty `200` response.

What's happening is, jQuery expects a json response body, but when the response comes back empty, json parsing fails and the error callback is triggered.

My solution was to override the Model's `sync` method:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  // Fix for empty DELETE response
  sync: function(method, model, options) {
    if (method === 'delete') {
      options.dataType = 'html';
    }
    Backbone.sync.call(this, method, model, options);
  }
});
```

This works because `options` is passed to jQuery's `ajax` call and we're instructing jQuery not to expect json.